# Get the base url of application in Java

Tags: java, xpages

Is there a nicer way to get the base URL of ref to the current application in XPages/Java?

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
XSPContext context = XSPContext.getXSPContext(facesContext);
XSPUrl url = context.getUrl();
String host = url.getScheme() + "://" + url.getHost() + "/" + url.getPath();
```

Comment: Surely `context.getUrl().toString()` would do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just a little bit nicer:

```
String serverPathNsf = url.getAddress().replace(url.getSiteRelativeAddress(context), "")
```

`url.getAddress()` gives you server + path to nsf + xsp

```
    http://yourServer/pathTo.nsf/your.xsp
```

`url.getSiteRelativeAddress(context)` gives you the xsp

```
    /your.xsp
```

and `url.getAddress().replace(url.getSiteRelativeAddress(context), "")` returns server + path to nsf

```
    http://yourServer/pathTo.nsf
```